# RegEx to remove an empty attribute? E.g. if (class=" " || class="") remove; else leave class

Tags: javascript, regex

This question is for general purpose, and no, "you should never regex html"...

What is the regex to remove an empty attribute, such as

```
class="" or class="   "
```

without knowing the number of whitespaces inbetween " "?

Plus: Leaving the class tag untouched if there are other chars inside?

I got a [solution for complicated regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12412388/regex-to-remove-all-styles-but-leave-color-and-background-color-if-they-exist) yesterday, however, I was not able to strip that down to the specific case mentioned above.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with the following regex:

```
/class="\s*?"/
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about checking whether or not it's actually inside an HTML tag, you can use:

```
[a-z]+="\s*"
```

This could be used with `.replace()` such as:

```
str = str.replace(/[a-z]+="\s*"/ig, '');
```

The `i` will ignore case while the `g` will "replace" all instances matched.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `/class="\s*"/` with an empty string.